# Mutually Exclusive Events Question

Tags: probability

2 students applied for a scholarship that will be given to two candidates. The probability of the first student's selection is 2/7 and that of the other student's selection is 5/9. What is the probability that "only one" of those students is selected?

My take on this question:
Let P(A) = 2/7; P(B) = 5/9.
Since only one student is selected, I know that these events are mutually exclusive.
Then, P(A U B) = P(A) + P(B) = 2/7 + 5/9.

Why is this incorrect?

Comment: Well, perhaps both get selected.  But the problem is poorly phrased,  Surely the events are not independent.  Knowing that one student won ought to lower the chances for the other.

Comment: Only one student is selected means that the other one is not selected. So the prob. is $\frac{2}{7}\cdot \frac{4}{9}+\frac{5}{7}\cdot \frac{5}{9}$

Comment: @callculus42 that's the right answer but how do you come to that? Would you mind explaining it better and perhaps explaining why 2/7 + 5/9 is incorrect?

Comment: @peru_45 It is required that exactly one student is selected. There a two cases: 1. First candidate is selected and the second candidate is not selected. 2. First candidate is not selected and the second candidate is  selected. For each case we have a product of the probability and the converse probability. // P(A U B) is wrong here, since it means that **at least one** student is selected. If you would calculate it, it would be $2/7 + 5/9-2/7*5/9$, since the events are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Can you explain why $2/7 + 5/9$ is incorrect?*"

$\Pr(A\cup B)$ is not equal to $\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$ except in very specific circumstances, namely when there is (*effectively*) no overlap between the events $A$ and $B$.  More generally $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$.  Here in your problem, there *is* overlap between the events $A$ and $B$ as you have defined them.  That is to say, it is possible that both of your students get the scholarship.  If you were intending to calculate $\Pr(A\cup B)$ here then you are missing that $-\Pr(A\cap B)$ in your calculation.

This is however not even what the question is asking for... $A\cup B$ is the event that the first student *or* the second student **or both** are selected.  To answer the question of "*What is the probability that* **exactly one** (*and not both*) *students are selected?*" you are really looking for $\Pr(A\triangle B)$ or equivalently written $\Pr((A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B))$ or equivalently expanded as $\Pr(A\cup B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

However you choose to expand and approach this, you will wind up with an expression along the lines of $\dfrac{2}{7}+\dfrac{5}{9}-2\Pr(A\cap B)$.

To finish the problem, we must make an assumption.  The assumption to make is that there are presumably a "*large number of applicants*" to the point where the success of our first student's application effectively does not impact the success of our second student's application.  In such a scenario we may calculate $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$... however it must be stressed that this is typically *not* going to be true.  Normally $\Pr(A\cap B)$ is not going to equal $\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$ and this is only going to be true when $A$ and $B$ are in fact independent events.

---

So, you could write this as:

$$\Pr(A\triangle B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-2\Pr(A\cap B) = \dfrac{2}{7}+\dfrac{5}{9}-2\times \dfrac{2\times 5}{7\times 9}$$

or as

$$\Pr((A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B)) = \dfrac{2}{7}\times (1-\dfrac{5}{9})+(1-\dfrac{2}{7})\times \dfrac{5}{9}$$

or similar...

Answer (score 0):

P(A ∪ B) describes the probability of A, B or both. You are interested in exactly 1 student being selected so must subtract P(A ∩ B).
Therfore, you could do this problem by subtracting P(neither are selected) and P(both are selected) from 1:
1 - ($\frac{5}{7}$ * $\frac{4}{9}$) - ($\frac{2}{7}$ * $\frac{5}{9}$) = 1 - $\frac{20}{36}$ - $\frac{10}{36}$ = $\frac{23}{63}$
P(exactly one is selected) = $\frac{23}{63}$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\Omega:=\lbrace (0,0),(1,0), (1,1), (0,1)\rbrace$ and the set of all subsets as $\sigma$-Algebra.

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on the set of all subsets of $\Omega$ satisfying

$\mathbb{P}(\lbrace (1,0), (1,1)\rbrace)=2/7$

and

$\mathbb{P}(\lbrace (0,1), (1,1)\rbrace)=5/9$.

If we assume that $\lbrace (1,0), (1,1)\rbrace$ and $\lbrace (0,1), (1,1)\rbrace$ are independent then

you are looking for

$\mathbb{P}(\lbrace(1,0), (0,1)\rbrace)=\mathbb{P}(\lbrace (0,1), (1,1)\rbrace\cap \lbrace (1,0), (1,1)\rbrace^c\cup \lbrace (0,1), (1,1)\rbrace^c\cap \lbrace (1,0), (1,1)\rbrace)=5/9\cdot (1-2/7)+2/7\cdot (1-5/9)$.

Now you should also be able to tell me what the probability is

- that both students get selected,
- only the first student gets selected,
- only the second student gets selected,
- none of both students get selected,
- both or none of both get selected.

Note that you can use the fact that if $A$ and $B$ are independent, so are $A$ and $B^c$.